# formatting the default text in a PDF text field

Tags: pdf

I am trying to format the text size in a PDF for the default text. I also have it set (with a script) so that the default text is removed when the user is focused on the field, but cant get the default value to re-appear if the user fails to enter any data.

here is a link to a piece of what I have so far: [sample_pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41988784/sample_pdf_form.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the default text on focus is correct.

Now, to show it again, you reverse it in the onBlur event:

```
if (event.value == "") {
event.target.value = event.target.defaultValue
}
```

and that should do it. You may add more conditions for "not filled", but the principle is the same.